# Create filtered JSON form exising JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I got below JSON data:

```
[
{
    "ric": "ADAG.DE",
    "sedol": "5653487",
    "quantity": 107479,
    "activityQuantity": null,
    "businessDate": 20141023
},
{
    "ric": "ADAG.DE",
    "sedol": "BBJPFY1",
    "quantity": 2758,
    "activityQuantity": null,
    "businessDate": 20141023
}]
```

And from above JSON data I have to create below JSON data with ric as Key and businessDate and quantity as values below using JavaScript:

```
[
{
    "key": "ADAG.DE",
    "values": [
        [
            20141023,
            107479
        ],
        [
            20141023,
            2758
        ]
    ]
}]
```

Would you please help me. This question is not duplicate as I searched all where I see it has only one key with one value where I have to create one key with set of two dimensional array value JSON.

Comment: This question is not duplicate as I searched all where I see it has only one key with one value where I have to create one key with set of two dimensional array value JSON

Comment: It's the same concept

Comment: I wouldn't have ask above question if I had answer of it. Probably its very easy you to create. If its same concept would you please create above JSON please as I trying to create but not successful yet.

Comment: @user3468976 Then show your attempts.